# rsync from NTFS to ext4

Tags: ntfs, rsync, ext4

I made a backup of a folder on an external NTFS drive on an ext4 folder and it went fine. The problem I have now is that rsync ignores already existing (and unchanged) files and syncs everything even though the vast majority of files are on the backup folder.

Comment: The problem is clear, but the question not.

Comment: Add option `-i` to see why it wants to update the file, and add this to your OP.

Comment: NTFS does not support Linux permissions & ownership. Not sure how it translates timestamps, but also different. Rsync has so many settings there may be one, but do not know as I only use ext4 to ext4.